# Wix Managed Bootstrapper fails to unload WtsApi32.dll on uninstall of upgraded bundle

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I have created a managed bootstrapper (wix v3.9.1208.0) that works a little like Visual studio/Resharper installers which works great in that:

1. On install it installs pre-requisites and installs or skips what you select from the list of available applications that are bundled up.
2. If you modify then it will uninstall/skip/install you selections.
3. Uninstall removes all non pre-requisite applications.

My problem is when I Upgrade. The applications being upgraded are installed with no problem and even the uninstall of the previous bundle gets kicked off at the end however this is where it all goes wrong.
It gets to the ApplyComplete event where I call the bootstrappers InvokeShutdown and then it stops. The last few lines of my log getting to this point is as follows with the error at the end.

```
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i207: Planned related bundle: {afe9a965-64d2-4656-a968-95ad1ca320a1}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i201: Planned package: App1, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i201: Planned package: LicenceManager, state: Present, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i201: Planned package: vcRedistx64, state: Present, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i201: Planned package: NetFx452Web, state: Present, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i201: Planned package: dotnetfx35setup.exe, state: Present, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i000: Executing OnPlanComplete
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i300: Apply begin
[2934:22D0][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {93F9AE5C-EC11-4122-8F1D-11A4EEDAF4C9}, package: App1
[2934:22D0][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {2326EAF9-A4C2-4AE0-A22B-8B8640B1A151}, package: LicenceManager
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i000: Executing OnExecuteComplete
[2934:22D0][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {41b57ce1-0fc2-4761-9779-fb0dab861ce9}
[2934:22D0][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i352: Removing cached bundle: {41b57ce1-0fc2-4761-9779-fb0dab861ce9}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{41b57ce1-0fc2-4761-9779-fb0dab861ce9}\
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i000: Executing OnApplyComplete
[2950:1B18][2015-02-26T16:03:03]i000: OnApplyComplete() - Invoking shutdown due to Action being Uninstall
[2950:20E8][2015-02-26T16:03:03]e000: Unable to load DLL 'WtsApi32.dll': Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I looked at procmon to see if i could get any more insight and found these as the last few entries. There is a delete pending for the WtsApi32.dll just before the log entry for the dll being locked. Is the shutdown trying to happen too early?

```
08:01:50.8330216    Bootstrapper.exe    12112   CreateFile  C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6ab12c5b-558c-42b4-9f60-958771befc1c}\POWRPROF.DLL    DELETE PENDING  Desired Access: Read Attributes,    Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
08:01:50.8335070    Bootstrapper.exe    12112   CreateFile  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WtsApi32.dll  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
08:01:50.8336118    Bootstrapper.exe    12112   CreateFile  C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6ab12c5b-558c-42b4-9f60-958771befc1c}\WtsApi32.dll    DELETE PENDING  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
08:01:50.8341131    Bootstrapper.exe    12112   WriteFile   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\BundleLog_20150227080127.log   SUCCESS Offset: 6,794, Length: 146
```

The package folder where the wtsapi32.dll is trying to be deleted from does show as access denied if I try and go there in windows explorer.

Comment: That last error message `Unable to load DLL...` is coming from your BA right?  Because the only reference to wtsapi32.dll in Burn I can find is ifdef'd out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out someone had commented out my logic in my custom BA override of Run to show the view in certain scenarios and not others. So when the Command.Display was Embedded the code was trying to display my view and hence I think dlls were getting locked on shutdown. 
Oh well at least the cause is found!